# What is a swap-with-memory instruction?

Tags: parallel-computing, memory-hardware

I am reading an article on algorithms for parallel computing and came across the following sentence.  What do they mean by a swap-with-memory instruction?

> Our algorithm provides reasonable latency in the absence of contention, requires only a constant amount of space per lock, and requires no hardware support other than a **swap-with-memory instruction**.

J. M. Mellor-Crummey and M. L. Scott, *Algorithms for Scalable Synchronization on Shared-Memory Multiprocessors*. ACM Transactions on Computer Systems, 9(1):21–65, 1991. ([PDF](http://web.mit.edu/6.173/www/currentsemester/readings/R06-scalable-synchronization-1991.pdf))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A swap-with-memory instruction swaps a register's value with that of a memory location.  An example of such an instruction would be the Intel 8086 **XCHG** instruction which can swap a register value with memory or swap two register values.  Another example would be the indirect modes of the Zilog Z80 **EX** instruction, which swapped register values with memory locations at the top of the stack.

Comment: You left out one important part: A swap-with-memory instruction must be atomic.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume the `fetch_and_store` instruction is meant. Look at the footnotes on page 2:

> 1) `Fetch-and-store` exchanges a register with memory.

Keep in mind that this paper is over 20 years old, so the terminology can seem unfamiliar. However, often the semantic of the operations/instructions used in such papers are described in detail somewhere in the text.